# Using scrapy to digest loosely formatted, primive html into blocks of text

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Just introduced to Scrapy. Have gone through the basic tutorial, but feel I don't quite grok how to use it.

Simple case I need to parse is like:

```
BASIC CASE
<li>
    <b>Descriptive Title</b>
    <br>
    The_first_paragraph_of_text
    <p>Second paragraphs of text</p>
    ...
    <p>Nth Paragraph of text</p>
</li>
```

What I want to do is generate a database record with two columns, "title" and "body_text".  Title comes from the 'Descriptive Title'  and the body_text comes from taking all paragraphs of text and concatenating into a block of text.

I wrote something simple like

```
"""pulls out the Descriptive Title and all the <p>-wrapped paragraphs but misses the first paragraph (which isn't wrapped in a <p>"""
for sel in response.xpath("//li"):
    b = sel.xpath('b').extract()
    print "b = {0}\n".format(b)    
    for p in sel.xpath('p'):
        paragraph = p.xpath('text()').extract()
        print"\n{0}".format(paragraph)
```

But this doesn't catch the unwrapped first paragraph, only paragraph two and onwards.  And also, it's not robust to variations of the `<li>` html blocks.

In one variation the first paragraph is sometimes wrapped in italics.

```
ITALICS COMPLICATION
<li>
    <b>Descriptive Title</b>
    <br>
    <i>Occasionally The_first_paragraph_of_text is in italics</i>
    <p>Second paragraphs of text</p>
    ...
    <p>Nth Paragraph of text</p>
</li>
```

In another variation, sometimes `<li>` are embedded inside some of the paragraph blocks.

```
SUB LIST-ITEM COMPLICATION
<li>
    <b>Descriptive Title</b>
    <br>
    <i>Occasionally The_first_paragraph_of_text is in italics</i>
    <p>Second paragraphs of text</p>
    <p>Sometimes paragraphs will have lists inside them
        <li>idea 1</li>
        <li>idea 2</li>
        <li>idea N</li>
    </p>
    <p>Nth Paragraph of text</p>
</li>
```

I suspect I'm not really digesting the html file in a "scrapythonic" way.  What's the right approach to write a more robust Selector(s) to pull out what I want?

Answer (score 1):

More of an xpath question than a scrapy question.
If your title is always in the first element, being a `<b>` tag
it's easy as `sel.xpath('b[1]/text()')`.

If I were you however I would add some strict assertions
to make it fail rather than scrap the wrong title text
because a `<b>` tag can often play other roles.
Try:
`title, = sel.xpath('*[1][self::b and count(node())=count(text())]')`
`title = u'\n'.join(sel.xpath('text()'))`
This reads as follows (assertions in parentheses):
*There must exist one and only one tag (asserted by `title, =`)

that is the first tag (asserted by `[1]`)

and is a `<b>` (asserted by `self::b`)

and has only text nodes (asserted by `count(text())=count(node())`)*

For the body text, 
you'll have to get used to the use of html for formatting
unless you are scraping a site
that formats its main content very simply
(eg arranged `<p>` tags).

You can get all the text descendants in document order with:
`sel.xpath('.//text()')`
However `<script>` and `<style>` tags may show up unwanted text;
you don't want your body text to be filled with javascript/css gibberish.
You can prevent them from being selected with:
`sel.xpath('.//text()[not(parent::script or parent::style)]')`
Then, you'd probably want to join the extracted text with `u'\n'.join()`

This will solve your problem but it will not handle all unwanted tags.
Play around with `lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(style=True)`
(documented here http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html)
and consider finding a library that renders html to text.